# Preventing auto expansion of Gmail in the notification?

Tags: notifications, gmail

If I remember it correctly, Gmail used to show only a digest (the title/sender/time) of new e-mails in the system notification, and I had to expand it manually.

I don't know since when it changed but now, but now it seems to be expanded by default. To me, this is very annoying because often I do not want to read the e-mails right away, and when I swipe down to open the system notification menu for other things like stopping music, the big new e-mail notification takes up the entire screen, making it difficult to swipe up to close the system notification menu.

Is there any way to prevent automatic expansion? That is, I want Gmail to show only the digest in the notification, and the full body only when I manually expand the notification.

Comment: provide device model and android version for further help

Comment: Android version is 11, and probably the phone model does not matter. I can't think of why Google would have decided Gmail act differently in terms of expanding the notification on different phones.

Comment: The phone model doesn't matter, true. but can you atlest tell the phone brand so that i understand which android skin it is running? for example Samsung's OneUI or AOSP etc